# GPIO protection with diodes

Tags: microcontroller, diodes, gpio

I've got a question regarding diodes you can see on the schematic.

In my circuit VCC is 12V (I have separated power supply for MCU) and the current on this line may even reach 1.5 A.
Can I safetly use diode like 1N4004 which has max current about 1A? I'm also not sure how this wiring could protect my GPIO pin.

May I ask somebody to explain this? It was recommended to me to use such wiring, but I not longer have contact with the author of it, so I can't ask him for explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESD protection diodes don't have any current through them in normal operation, so the current on the power rail  they're connected to doesn't matter. They are only there to provide a current path for ESD events, discharging the static charge into the power supply instead of into the fragile logic circuitry.

The way the circuit works is that the diodes clamp the discharge to the power rails (with a diode drop of margin added), so instead of charging up to thousands of volts until something breaks in a discharge event, the charge can just go to the power supply and decoupling capacitors, with the voltage on the fragile pin limited to safe values.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Now it's clear.